# To simplify MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have three table in MySQL DB as follow

> `users(id_user - 99911, username - heman, status - manager)
>
> service(id_service - 11, service_name - blabla)
>
> auth_service(id_user - 99911, id_service - 11)

All these three table are not relational. I want just to do it in PHP code. I have tried some queries to display services which are authorised to an user who is only manager.

```
select s.service_name from service s 
  inner join auth_service a on s.id_service = a.id_service 
  inner join users u on a.id_user = 99911 
order by s.service_name and u.status='manager';
```

but it displays multiple times of same records has been sorted. Where is the problem? How do I avoid repeated display of the same records?

Comment: They're not relational? So it's just coincidence that auth_service has columns which appear to 'relate' to the other tables. SQL is a *structured query* language. The clue is in the title!

Answer (score 0):

The following query give you all services which are authorized by users who are manager.

```
select distinct s.service_name, a.id_user
from service s inner join auth_service a 
on s.id_service = a.id_service 
where a.id_user in (select id_user from users where status = 'manager') 
order by s.service_name
```

Answer (score -1):

Use GROUP BY Clause.

```
select DISTINCT s.service_name from service s 
  inner join auth_service a on s.id_service = a.id_service 
  inner join users u on a.id_user = 99911 
order by s.service_name and u.status='manager'
```

Comment: GROUP BY may work, and it may even be performant. But it carries a risk (should the query evolve) of returning indeterminate results. SELECT's DISTNCT modifier is the correct solution here.